# How does Haskell type-check infinite recursive values?

Tags: haskell, types, infinite, typechecking, type-systems

Define this data type:

```
data NaturalNumber = Zero | S NaturalNumber
    deriving (Show)
```

In Haskell (compiled using GHC), this code will run without warning or error:

```
infinity = S infinity
inf1 = S inf2
inf2 = S inf1
```

So both recursive and mutually recursive infinitely deep values pass the type check.

However, the following code gives an error:

```
j = S 'h'
```

The error states `Couldn't match expected type ‘NaturalNumber’ with actual type 'Char'`. The (same) error persists even if I set

```
j = S (S (S (S ... (S 'h')...)))
```

with a hundred or so nested `S`'s.

How can Haskell tell that `infinity` is a valid member of `NaturalNumber` but `j` is not?

Interestingly, it also allows:

```
bottom = bottom
k = S bottom
```

Does Haskell merely try to prove incorrectness of a program, and if it fails to do so then allows it? Or is Haskell's type system not Turing complete, so if it allows the program then the program is provably (at the type level) correct?

(If the type system (in the formal semantics of Haskell, instead of only the type checker) is Turing complete, then it will either fail to realize some correctly typed programs are correct or some incorrectly typed programs are incorrect, due to the undecidability of the halting problem.)

Comment: You may be interested in reading about Hindley-Milner type inference. GHC has a form of bidirectional typechecking. When looking at `infinity`, Haskell will attempt to synthesize `infinity :: NaturalNumber` (since it is constructed using `S :: NaturalNumber -> NaturalNumber`) and then check that `infinity :: NaturalNumber` (since `infinity` is the argument given to `S`).

Comment: OK -- so essentially it guesses at types (in some intelligent manner) and then attempts to see if then the types match up? Is there any guarantee of termination (of the type checker) with a correct result then?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well

```
S :: NaturalNumber -> NaturalNumber
```

In

```
infinity = S infinity
```

We start by assuming nothing: we assign `infinity` some unsolved type `_a` and try to figure out what it is. We know that we have applied `S` to `infinity`, so `_a` must be whatever is on the left side of the arrow in the constructor’s type, which is `NaturalNumber`. We know that `infinity` is the result of an application of `S`, so `infinity :: NaturalNumber`, again (if we got two conflicting types for this definition, we’d have to emit a type error).

Similar reasoning holds for the mutually recursive definitions. `inf1` must be a `NaturalNumber` because it appears as an argument to `S` in `inf2`; `inf2` must be a `NaturalNumber` because it is the result of `S`; etc.

The general algorithm is to assign definitions unknown types (notable exceptions are literals and constructors), and then to create constraints on those types by seeing how every definition is used. E.g. this must be some form of list because it’s being `reverse`d, and this must be an `Int` because it’s being used to look up a value from an `IntMap`, etc.

In the case of

```
oops = S 'a'
```

`'a' :: Char` as it’s a literal, but, also, we must have `'a' :: NaturalNumber` because it’s used as an argument to `S`. We get the obviously bogus constraint that the type of the literal must both be `Char` and `NaturalNumber`, which causes a type error.

And in

```
bottom = bottom
```

We start with `bottom :: _a`. The only constraint is `_a ~ _a`, because a value of type `_a` (`bottom`) is being used where a value of type `_a` is expected (on the RHS of the definition of `bottom`). Since there is nothing to further constrain the type, the unsolved type variable is *generalized*: it gets bound by a universal quantifier to produce `bottom :: forall a. a`.

Note how both uses of `bottom` above have the same type (`_a`) while inferring the type of `bottom`. This breaks polymorphic recursion: every occurrence of a value within its definition is taken to be of the same type as the definition itself. E.g.

```
-- perfectly balanced binary trees
data Binary a = Leaf a | Branch (Binary (a, a))
-- headB :: _a -> _r
headB (Leaf x) = x -- _a ~ Binary _r; headB :: Binary _r -> _r
headB (Branch bin) = fst (headB bin)
-- recursive call has type headB :: Binary _r -> _r
-- but bin :: Binary (_r, _r); mismatch
```

So you need a type signature:

```
headB :: {-forall a.-} Binary a -> a
headB (Leaf x) = x
headB (Branch bin) = fst (headB {-@(a, a)-} bin)
-- knowing exactly what headB's signature is allows for polymorphic recursion
```

So: when something doesn't have a type signature, the type checker tries to assign it a type, and if it comes across a bogus constraint on its way, it rejects the program. When something has a type signature, the type checker descends into it to make sure it's correct (tries to prove it wrong, if you prefer to think of it that way).

Haskell’s type system is not Turing complete because there are heavy syntactic restrictions to prevent e.g. type lambdas (without language extensions), but it doesn’t suffice to make sure all programs run to completion without error because it still allows bottoms (not to mention all the unsafe functions). It provides the weaker guarantee that, if a program runs to completion without using an unsafe function, it will remain type-correct. Under GHC, with sufficient language extensions, the type system does become Turing complete. I don't think it allows ill-typed programs through; I think the most you can do is throw the compiler into an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks. This explains it, especially the last paragraph.

Comment: I think it's much more precise to say that the type checker tries to prove that the program is well-typed. Discovering a definite error is a special case of failing to type the program.